# Conditional expectation using derived distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, conditional

While [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189977/double-integral-to-compute-conditional-expectation) can be solved using some (hand) analysis and standard calculus, I would have thought that the following code would have worked:

```
Clear[x, y, c];
Expectation[x \[Conditioned] x + y > c, 
  x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[] && 
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]]
```

It doesn't.  Is there a way to use `Expectation` and `Conditioned` for this problem?

@AlexTournev caught my silly syntactic error:  One should use brackets, not &&.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Clear[x, y, c];
Expectation[
 x \[Conditioned] x + y > c, 
 {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[], 
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[]}]

(*

E^(-(c^2/4))/(Sqrt[\[Pi]] Erfc[c/2])

*)
```

Comment: Well... a simple syntactic error.  I hope you won't mind if I post this answer (citing you) on the source page.  Thanks!

Comment: OK! You can rewrite your code.